# Building height in OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, lidar

I was wondering if there are some free projects which enable extracting the building height information from openstreetmap data?

I downloaded data for a couple of large cities (Manhattan island, Munich...) and none of them contained the [height](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:height) information.

I googled a bit and found [a project where Lidar](https://vimeo.com/115361043) point clouds have been overlayed on top of openstreetmap data, and then the height of the building rooftops have been identified by checking the point's Z coordinates.

Are there any other free projects which enable defining the height of the buildings of openstreetmap data? At least for world's major (largest) cities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height of a building is difficult to obtain except when having official data. But the number of building levels is easy to obtain by just looking at the building. Maybe [building:levels](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:building:levels) is sufficient for your use-case? Also see [simple 3D buildings](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Simple_3D_buildings) for various other interesting information regarding 3D tagging.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply @scai.
I have just opened in QGIS the Manhattan, Munich and Barcelona openstreetmap data, and neither contains the ```building``` key. All three contain these: ```osm_id```,```name```,```type``` while QGIS additionally calculates the: ```Area```,```Perimeter```,```feature id```.
Does that mean that ```building:levels``` key is extremely rare? Do you happen to know a certain city which contains this key?

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong. Where do you get your data from exactly? Unfortunately I'm not familiar with QGIS. The building:levels key is only present on a subset of buildings of course. But I wouldn't call it rare. According to [taginfo](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/building%3Alevels) the OSM database contains this key currently 7 million times. See this [example for Munich](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/hqG).

Comment: I am downloading the openstreetmap data in shapefile format from ```http://extract.bbbike.org```.
Do all outlined buildings in the link you sent me contain the ```building:levels``` key?

Comment: Yes, they do. Maybe the extract from bbike doesn't contain these information.

Comment: Thank you @scai. I labeled your reply as the problem solving one.
Can I ask you for a favor please? Can you download the openstreetmap data of any part of Munich directly from openstreetmap.org and tell me if ```building:levels``` keys appear? I understand that they would have due to upper link you sent me, but I would be very grateful if you could do me this favor. Thank you.

Comment: Just follow the [overpass-turbo link from my first comment](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/hqG), go to "Export" and [download the raw data](https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=way%0A%20%20%5B%22building%3Alevels%22%5D%0A%20%20%2848.083469087897214%2C11.444149017333984%2C48.19264105833093%2C11.737518310546875%29%3B%0A%28._%3B%3E%3B%29%3B%0Aout%3B). This is an XML file containing lots of building:levels keys. See [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) in the OSM wiki to learn more about this API.

Comment: Thank you @scai. Is it possible to directly download (through url) the xml or any other data type through overpass-turbo, without having to manually click on "Export"?
Similar to this: ```http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/map?bbox=11.54,48.14,11.543,48.145```

Comment: Yes. overpass-turbo is just a frontend to Overpass API. Simply create an Overpass API query for the data your are interested in. See the [examples from the language guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Usage_examples:_Simple_queries_for_tags_and_bounding_boxes). You can specify a bbox or create even more advanced queries where you can specify a specific city boundary and similar things.

Comment: Thank you @scai. But still means I need to manually click on the "Export" button?

Comment: No, because you don't have to use overpass-turbo at all. Clicking on the export button just converts the overpass-turbo query into an Overpass API query (which is essentially the same with only very few exceptions). See the "raw data" link from one of my previous comments, it calls Overpass API directly. Just build your query, optionally test it with overpass-turbo, then run it on Overpass API. No clicking involved if you don't want to :)

Comment: Thank you for your patience once again @scai.
Is [this is the link](https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=way%0A%20%20%5B%22building%3Alevels%22%5D%0A%20%20%2848.083469087897214%2C11.444149017333984%2C48.19264105833093%2C11.737518310546875%29%3B%0A%28._%3B%3E%3B%29%3B%0Aout%3B) you mentioned ? The downloaded file is named ```interpreter``` and does not have any extension. Should I consider it to be an .osm file? You told me in your upper reply that it is an XML file, but are these two the same or not?

Comment: Yes, this file is a valid [OSM XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) file. Note that Overpass API also supports JSON and CSV output.